# How to set Alesis Q25 to transmit on only single midi channel into Logic Pro

Tags: midi, daw, logic-pro, midi-controller-keyboard, mac

I've got an Alesis Q25 hooked up to my Mac running Logic Pro. Everything works great. What I want to do is send midi data from the Q25 on only one midi channel, so I can have another midi controller connected at the same time (on different channel). I think I'm setting the channel on the Q25, but in Logic the signal comes through no matter what channel I choose for the track. I've looked through the manual, and many Logic tutorials, but remain stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!